# Status Expected :204 Actual :404

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc, spring-boot-test

hello please am new in intergration Tests. Am facing sopme difficulties with my assertion status.

**here is the error**

> java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
>   Expected :204
>   Actual   :404

**here is the test code**

```
    @Test
@Transactional
public void deleteCustomerTest() throws Exception{
        //initialize database
    customerRepository.saveAndFlush(customer);
    int dataBaseSizeBeforeDelete = customerRepository.findAll().size();

        //Get the customer to be deleted
        restCustomerMockMvc.perform(delete( "/v1/customers/{uidpk}", customer.getUidpk())
                .accept(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(status().isNoContent());

        //Validate the database is empty
    List<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(customers).hasSize(dataBaseSizeBeforeDelete - 1);
}
```

**here is the Request**

```
    @DeleteMapping(CUSTOMER_ID_ENDPOINT)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "The Customer was deleted", response = CustomerDto.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The Customer with the given uidpk id was not found", response = ResponseError.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Unexpected error")
})
@Timed
public ResponseEntity deleteCustomer(@PathVariable Long uidpk){
    log.debug("[CustomerResource] DELETE {} : Deleting customer ({})", CUSTOMER_ID_ENDPOINT, uidpk );

    try {
        customerService.delete(uidpk);
    }catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
        //No Customer found with this uidpk ID
        ResponseError error = new ResponseError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getReasonPhrase(), "The customer with id " + uidpk+ " was not found");
        log.error("[CustomerResource] Customer ({}) does not exist", uidpk);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error,null,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    log.debug("[CustomerResource] Customer ([]) deleted", uidpk);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null,null,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

when i click onto the function name its point at this line :   **.andExpect(status().isNoContent());**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You controller method always returns 404 (not found). So everything is working as expected.

If you want to return 402 (no content) you should add this after the delete statement: `return new ResponseEntity<>(null,null,HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);` and remove the return statement at the end of the method.

Comment: thanks so much for seing my error. Everything is ok. Thks a lot @Cyril